# getText() method in selenium is returning small letter instead

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gettext, innertext

getText() method is returning all small letters instead of as it is. When i try to assert the expected text I am facing error because of case sensitive issue. kindly anyone help me to resolve this issue.

**Error**:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [All content one platform] but found [all content one platform]
```

**code**:

```
String contentText = AllContent.getText();
    System.out.println("***********************" + contentText);
    Assert.assertEquals(contentText,"All content one platform");
```

**HTML**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX3yc.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation that small or large letter is issue , do not use get_text
just use text method after finding the element it will gives you exact text.
For me in python .... find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class name").text()
I hope this helps you man.

Comment: Thanks Fardad. unfortunately, selenium with java doesn't has text method. I've check other website too which is saying the same thing. Usually, getText() method is return sensitive text only. but I'm getting weird error.